# jQuery text() Method with loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to create Logout button, but I have no idea what to use.

How to keep the logout text changed to "Waiting.." in a few seconds, after which it switches to "Success"?

I still need to learn jquery.

```
function logout() {

    $("#logout").text("Waiting...", 3000);
    $("#logout").text("Success!", 1000);
    closeWindow();
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById('logout').addEventListener('click', logout);

});
```

HTML :

```
<button type="button" class="list-group-item" id="logout"> Log out</button>
```

Can you help me with references?

I learned from this reference : [**W3Schools.com**](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_text_set)

Comment: think no need ``document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded'``

Comment: for what is it? I don't know why I put it that way, I just see from the reference. thanks

Comment: are you using some `AJAX` or maybe a promise?

Comment: a couple more fiddles for fun.. https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/amefjhng/ https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/zt2rauut/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded' ....` is not needed & on `click` of the button update with `Success` message after 3 secs. Use `setTimeout` to introduce the delay

```js
function logout() {
  $("#logout").text("Waiting...", 3000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#logout").text("Success!", 1000);
  }, 3000)
}
document.getElementById('logout').addEventListener('click', logout);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="list-group-item" id="logout"> Log out</button>
```

Comment: can you help me? i have fontawesome in the button. i want to change text without change the fontawesome code .

Comment: just add the fontawesome class to the button

Comment: no, i mean, my button look like this `<button><i class="fa fa-sign-out"
></i> Logout</button>` when im change Logout text using my question method, fontawesome will be disappear.

Answer (score 1):

That may Help try this out:

```js
function logout(){
  $("button").text("waiting...");
  setInterval(sucess,3000)
}
function sucess(){
    $("button").css("background","green");
  $("button").text("successfull");
  clearInterval();
}

$("button").click(logout);
```

```css
button{
  background:orange;
  border:none;
  color:white;
  padding:20px 20px;
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
<button>Log out</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout to delay the execution of some code, like

```js
function logout() {
    $("#logout").text("Waiting...");
    /* using setTimeout delays execution of a code in JavaScript */
    setTimeout(function () {
      /* this code will execute after 3000 miliseconds or 3 seconds */
      $("#logout").text("Success!");
      // closeWindow();
    }, 3000);
}

$('#logout').on('click', logout);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="list-group-item" id="logout"> Log out</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess use **setTimeout** would be help you to delay and show the text in button

**html**

```
<button type="button" class="list-group-item" id="logout"> Log out</button>
```

**js**

```
$('#logout').click(function() {
    $(this).html('Waiting');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#logout').html('Success');
    }, 3000);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eqymkead/2/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **setTimeout** function.

Please look into code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 //Click Event
 $("#logout").click(function(){
  //Waiting will be here after 1 second
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#logout").text("Waiting...")
  },1000)
  //Waiting will be here after 3 second
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#logout").text("Success")
  },3000)
 })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="list-group-item" id="logout"> Log out</button>
```

Whenever button click event will be fire then a callback function. Inside that function I have written following code.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $("#logout").text("Waiting...")
},1000)
```

setTimeout function takes a call function and a time parameter(in milliseconds) I have provided 1000 milliseconds after 1000 milliseconds text will be **waiting**

same like I have again written for success.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#logout").text("Success")
},3000)
```